# Scatter Plot - Plotly in R - display values

Tags: r, plotly

I am using Plotly with R to create a scatter plot.  A reproducible example of the data is as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(Category = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Tea", "Coffee", 
"Noodles", "Ketchup", "Jam", "DetergentPowder", "DetergentCakes", 
"Dishwashbar", "DishwashLiquids", "FloorCleaners", "ToiletSoaps", 
"Shampoo", "Toothpaste", "ToothPowder", "Deos", "SkinCreams", 
"Facewash", "Handwash", "Icecreams"), class = "factor"), Kirana = c(25, 
16, 12), PettyTrader = c(146, 104, 55)), .Names = c("Category", 
"Kirana", "PettyTrader"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My plotly code is as follows:

```
plot_ly(df, x = ~Kirana, y = ~PettyTrader, text = ~Category, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = ~PettyTrader/5, color = ~Category,opacity = 0.5)) %>%
  layout(title = 'Shop Type by Categories Sold',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE))
```

My current plot show category labels upon hover over the bubble, but I want to display the labels by default.  How can I do this?

Comment: Ok...got it resolved through adding annotations.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your solution to the question? This might be helpful for other users looking for the same problem

Comment: @MaximilianPeters the plotly code with annotations `plot_ly(k, x = ~Kirana, y = ~PettyTrader, text = ~Category, type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers',
                marker = list(size = ~PettyTrader/5, color = "Red",opacity = 0.5)) %>%
          layout(title = 'Shop Type by Categories Sold',
                 xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, title = "Number of Kirana Shops"),
                 yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, title = "Number of Petty Traders")) %>%
            add_annotations(x = k$Kirana, y = k$PettyTrader, text = k$Category, showarrow = FALSE)`